# How to put re-direct to Courier site with consignment number of item?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on project e-commerce project, where I need to redirect to mentioned courier site of shipping product with it's consignment number, so that user don't need enter manually consignment number to courier site, It automatically take the consignment number.

I am able to redirect the courier site, but how I will able to put consignment number on the site so that not require to put manually by customer....

I am using Angular, HTML5 and for backend using django....

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <b>Courier No.</b>{{courier_number}} &nbsp <a target="_blank" href="{{ 'http://' + web_url}}"> courier</a>                 
</div>
```

Comment: You can pass it as query parameter and courier site can check and process accordingly.

Comment: @Rajesh could you suggest me some site or demo, where I can understand?

Comment: You can check *Gmail* for reference. In this link: **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox** `1` represents account number. So if you have added multiple accounts, changing this number updated mails according to account.

Comment: @Rajesh, sorry but I think this is not my answer, My question is how to direct to courier site and fill courier number it that site, so that we don't need to fill manually....

Comment: Full Explanation: You have to pass `tracking_id` as a query parameter. eg: *www.courier.com/?id=abc123*. This value will be accessed by *Their* code using `window.search`. On obtaining a valid value, courier site will load necessary data/view for this id else will show error page. This handling will be done by dev at courier site. You cannot directly change any value in some other site.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `consignment number` at the end of url like this

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <b>Courier No.</b>{{courier_number}} &nbsp <a target="_blank" href="{{ 'http://' + web_url + '?consignment_number=' + consignment_number}}"> courier</a>                 
</div>
```

than at the backend using **DJANGO** (you mentioned as backend), you can get this consignment number using `request.GET.get()` like this -

`consignment_number = request.GET.get('consignment_number','')`